# onChange event is not fire in simple unit test

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I wrote a really simple unit test, but the `handleChange` function does not get called.

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Component', () => {
    test('demo', (done) => {
        const handleChange = jest.fn();
        const {getByRole} = render(
            <input role="slider" type="range" onChange={({currentTarget}) => handleChange(currentTarget.value)}/>
        );
        fireEvent.change(getByRole('slider'), {currentTarget: {value: 10}});
        expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(10);
        done();
    });
})
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `fireEvent.change` has nothing to do with the event argument of the event handler. It only has specific keywords, and `currentTarget` does not exist. Instead, you should use `target`, which will work for both `target` and `currentTarget` properties of the event :

```js
fireEvent.change(getByRole('slider'), { target: { value: 10 } });
```